# Find the minimal polynomial for a matrix over a finite field

Tags: matrix

The code below is given in Eric Weisstein's  Math World article: [`Matrix Minimal Polynomial`](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixMinimalPolynomial.html).

```
MatrixMinimalPolynomial[a_List?MatrixQ,x_]:=Module[
    {
      i,
      n=1,
      qu={},
      mnm={Flatten[IdentityMatrix[Length[a]]]}
    },
    While[Length[qu]==0,
      AppendTo[mnm,Flatten[MatrixPower[a,n]]];
      qu=NullSpace[Transpose[mnm]];
      n++
    ];
    First[qu].Table[x^i,{i,0,n-1}]
  ]
```

Is it possible to adapt the code to give the minimal polynomial of a matrix over a finite field of prime order $p$.  Perhaps by adding `Modulus -> p` in the argument for [`NullSpace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NullSpace.html).

Comment: Yes, it seems to work fine with adding a `Modulus` argument to `NullSpace`. What is your question?

Comment: Hi Roman. Thanks.   The reason I am asking is that I am not clear on what the code is actually doing and consequently I am not sure if just adding a Modulus argument will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done in such a way:

```
ResourceFunction["MatrixMinimalPolynomial"][{{22,-16},{25,-18}}, x,Extension->alg,Modulus->5]
```

> `1 + 4*x + 4*x^2`

Of course, the above matrix is treated by mod 5. The theory is stated [here](https://ssmr.ro/bulletin/pdf/56-2/articol_8.pdf).

Comment: This is fine (as in +1). Just wanted to add that the `Extension` option can be omitted if there is no algebraic extension under consideration.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: No, in 13.1 on Windows 10 `ResourceFunction["MatrixMinimalPolynomial"][{{22, -16}, {25, -18}}, x,
  Modulus -> 5]` produces `Last[{}] . {1}` and the error "Last::nolast: {} has zero length and no last element". The documentation on this option is unclear.

Comment: Hi user64494.  Thanks.  I accepted your answer already but I think there is a problem.  For example:  Let the matrix over $\mathbb{F}_2$ be {{0,1,0,0},{1,1,0,0},{0,0,0,1},{0,0,1,1}}.  The minimal polynomial should be $x^2 + x + 1$.  But using your code I get $x^3 + 1.

Comment: Thanks both of you for pointing out those bugs. I'll look into them.

Comment: I updated` ResourceFunction["MatrixMinimalPolynomial"]` to fix the two issues noted here. I hope there are no further issues (but of course will look into any that get noted).